# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum output

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, sdk

When I save a video in Photos Album by using **UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum**, how can I retrieve it's new asset URL in **assets-library://asset/asset.mov....** format

```
//outputURL.path is : file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/4535724C-7ABD-4F00-A363-9A62022F8EB0/tmp/trim.E8CD7632-7C52-4EA4-A462-8C5131B214AA.MOV.exp.mov

UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL.path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`, you can use the `-[ALAssetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL completionBlock (ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock]` method ([Apple Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:))

For example:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoPathURL
                           completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) 
{ 
    /* process assetURL */ 
}];
```

**Important Note**: The important thing to remember when dealing with ALAssetsLibrary is that the assetURL is only valid for the lifetime of the ALAssetsLibrary instance. So ensure you hold a reference to library until after you have finished processing the assetURL and any associated ALAsset.

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is now deprecated